# color log not outputing color formatting mention in log config file

Tags: logging

I have the following set in my logging.config file

```
[formatter_simpleFormatter]
class=colorlog.ColoredFormatter
format=%(log_color)s[%(log_color)s%(asctime)s] %(log_color)s%(filename)s [line: %(log_color)s%(lineno)d] : %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s
```

but still output in terminal is not color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your color formatting, and it seems your code runs quite well

```
formatert = "%(log_color)s[%(log_color)s%(asctime)s] %(log_color)s%(filename)s [line: %(log_color)s%(lineno)d] : %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s"

logger = colorlog.getLogger('')
colored_handler = colorlog.StreamHandler()
colored_handler.setFormatter(colorlog.ColoredFormatter( \
    formatert,
    reset=True,
    log_colors={
        'DEBUG':    'cyan',
        'INFO':     'green',
        'WARNING':  'yellow',
        'ERROR':    'red',
        'CRITICAL': 'red,bg_white',
    },))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(colored_handler) 

logger.log(logging.DEBUG, "DEBUG message")
logger.log(logging.INFO, "INFO message")
logger.log(logging.WARNING, "WARNING message")
logger.log(logging.ERROR, "ERROR message")
logger.log(logging.CRITICAL, "CRITICAL message")
```

[image: Output Result]